# AWT: Component in ScrollPane: repainting only viewport/visible area

Tags: java, awt, scrollpane

I have a custom `Component` which extends `Canvas`, which I place in a `ScrollPane`. When the internal state of my component changes, I call it's `repaint()` method. However this results in full repaints (the bounds of the Graphics object passed to the component's paint method are the size of the component, not the size of the viewport). This is a problem because the component can become very large (10,000+ px) and has complicated painting logic.

The following code exemplifies this problem:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.ScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScrollPaneTest {
    static class MyCanvas extends Canvas {
        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            Rectangle clipBounds = g.getClipBounds();
            System.out.println("paint " + clipBounds.toString());
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawString(clipBounds.toString(), 20, 20);
        }

//      Attempted solution: doesn't work; MyCanvas.paint() doesn't get called at all.
//      @Override
//      public void repaint(long tm, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
//          System.out.println(tm + " " + x + " " + y + " "
//                  + width + " " + height);
//          getParent().repaint();
//      }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();
        frame.add(pane);

        MyCanvas mc = new MyCanvas();
        pane.add(mc);
        mc.setBounds(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
        mc.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println("keypressed");
                mc.repaint();
            }
        });
        mc.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

The problem: when a key is pressed and repaint(), then paint(Graphics) is called, the `clipBounds` printed always encompass the entire MyCanvas:

```
paint java.awt.Rectangle[x=0,y=0,width=1000,height=1000]
```

instead of just the visible area (400x200). I have searched Google/SO but didn't find anything relevant; does anyone know how to change this or figure out the visible area in the `paint` method?

Comment: If the clipping bounds of the Graphics are not been set to the viewport area, you will need to check what the parent is, of its a ScrollPane, then check its viewportSize property

Comment: @MadProgrammer A bit of a hack; I guess that's what I get for using AWT xD Thanks in any case!

Comment: Alot comes down to the fact that, generally, painting of the components is, generally, done by the OS itself and not AWT, so it's not optimised the same way that Swing is